# Re-open a bootstrap dropdown menu after chosen an element?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make sure that when I select an element of a dropdown menu it closes and then I can reopen it?

This is my code, if I select an item the menu closes but then I can not reopen it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.sorting").on('click', function(e) {
        $("#sort").dropdown("toggle");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown" id="sort">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ordina per
          <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>                                
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="sorting" value="Premio">Premio</a></li>
          <li><a class="sorting" value="Recenti">Recenti</a></li>
          <li><a class="sorting" value="Deadline">Deadline</a></li>
          <li><a class="sorting" value="Numero Partecipanti">Numero Partecipanti</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to handle event onclick event. Just remove your jquery code and it will work.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown" id="sort">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ordina per
          <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>                                
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="sorting" value="Premio">Premio</a></li>
          <li><a class="sorting" value="Recenti">Recenti</a></li>
          <li><a class="sorting" value="Deadline">Deadline</a></li>
          <li><a class="sorting" value="Numero Partecipanti">Numero Partecipanti</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```